# Jenkins build frequency based on previous build status

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I have a Jenkins pipeline which is scheduled to trigger every 4 hours. However, my requirements is that once the build fails, I want the builds to happen more frequently and keep sending constant reminders that the build is broken. In short, the build schedule must depend on the status of the previous build.

Is that possible in Jenkins?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Scripted Pipeline, you can do something like this :

```
def triggers = []

if(currentBuild.getPreviousBuild().result != 'SUCCESS') {
    triggers << cron('0 */1 * * *') // every hour
} else {
    triggers << cron('0 */4 * * *') // every 4 hours
}

properties ([
    pipelineTriggers(triggers)
])

node {
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't think of a direct way but you can have a workaround. You can have a replica of the same job(let's call it job 'B') and trigger it when the build of the first job fails(let's call it job 'A'). Now if B fails again then you can retrigger it(B) (adding some wait time) and send a notification after it fails, keep doing it until it passes. This will be done in a much easier way if you are using the scripted Jenkins pipeline. Hope this answer helps you in some way.